# AssertionFailedError when mocking toURI() method

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I am trying to mock `toURI()` method from `FileObject.java` class (this class belongs to `org.openide.filesystems` package).

The method declaration goes like this:

```
public final URI toURI() {
    // Compiled code
}
```

So far, I have this test code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String myUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    URI myURI = new URI(myUrl);
    FileObject mocked = Mockito.mock(FileObject.class);

    Mockito.when(mocked.toURI()).thenReturn(myURI);

    assertEquals(myURI, mocked.toURI());
}
```

However, when I run the test, it crashes in the line `Mockito.when(mocked.toURI()).thenReturn(myURI);` with the following error:

> Testcase: test(myapp.logicLayer.LogicTest):   FAILED File object Mock
>   for FileObject, hashCode: 443290224 returns null from getFileSystem()
>   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: File object Mock for FileObject,
>   hashCode: 443290224 returns null from getFileSystem()

I tried multiple workarounds, but couldn't find any way that worked.

I even tried to use `PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(FileObject.class, "toURI")).toReturn(myURI);`, but I get the same error, not to mention that this should be used in static methods, which is not the case.

<s>I am using Mockito 1.10.19. I googled around and managed to see that only version 2 of Mockito is able to mock final methods. My guess is that this can be the problem, but I am really not sure.</s>

Edit: just tested with Mockito 2.8.9 and the problem persists.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is happening because this is a **final method**.

Since Mockito 2.1.0 is possible to mock final method/classes. From Mockito [documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable):

> For a long time our users suffered a disbelief when Mockito refused to
>   mock a final class. Mocking of final methods was even more
>   problematic, causing surprising behavior of the framework and
>   generating angry troubleshooting. The lack of mocking finals was a
>   chief limitation of Mockito since its inception in 2007   (...)  it
>   can be done via the mockito extension mechanism by creating the file
>   src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

In oder to achieve final method mocking, you should, create the file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` cotaining the single line:

`mock-maker-inline`

And mockito will be able to mock final methods.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Updated to mockito 2 and added the file, but the problem persists. I tried to place the file in various different directories, but in none of them it seemed to work.

Comment: Are you running it in a Maven project? How are you running your unit tests? I tested with your code, and worked after adding the file.

Comment: No, I'm not using maven (I know that I should, though, but I am trying to avoid it for now at least). Instead, I downloaded Powermock and it's dependencies (which already bring mockito jar file) from their GitHub page [https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Downloads](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Downloads). I also added mockito-inline.jar to the libraries, but even after that it didn't work. Should it be lacking some dependency?

Comment: I think that's the problem! The path `src/test/resources/` is the resource test files for maven. I don't know where exatlcy the config file should be in this case (maybe you cloud create the `mockito-extensions` in you current path?).

Comment: Oh, I see... guess I will have to move to maven at once. When I finish doing so, I manage to run the test, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: After several hours moving my project to maven and dealing with the hell of Netbeans api transitive dependencies I managed to make the project run. Your solution was spot on. Thank you very much again! Answer accepted.